# How To save all the attachments from the mail in the outlook without specifying the attachment name

Tags: python, outlook

I am new to python. I am trying to save all the attachment from the email **without specifying the attachment name** from the outlook.

We need to download the attachment with the subject name.

because attachment can come in any name and also i need to download the attachment only for past 2 days.

Could anyone help me. Below is my code

```
    from win32com.client import Dispatch
import time
import datetime
import re
outlook = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder("6")
all_inbox = inbox.Items
val_date = datetime.date.today()
 
sub_today = 'test4'
att_today = '20201018_2.xlsx'    
#att_today = re.match(regex_, )
for msg in all_inbox:
    if msg.Subject.find(sub_today) != -1 and msg.SentOn.date() == val_date:
        break

for att in msg.Attachments:
    if att.FileName == att_today:
        print(att_today)
        break

try:
    print(att.FileName)
    #att.SaveAsFile("C:/Users/Shwettha/Downloads/attachment/"+ att.FileName)
    att.SaveAsFile(os.path.join("D:\Script\Monitoring",att.FileName))
    print("SUCCESSFUL","Attachments Downloaded")
except:
    print("ERROR","Attachment Download Failed")
```

Comment: set a filter, see exmple https://stackoverflow.com/a/59702194/4539709